# Removing quotes from the start and end - for fields with blanks

Tags: sql-server

This is the code I've managed to research. The whole table is imported from SQL, as NOT NULL. I get an error message when running it, "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function". It only seems to give this error message, if a field has blank entries in it.

How do I change this script to only run if the field is not null?

```
UPDATE [Majestic].[dbo].Fields_custom
    SET maxlength=left(right(cast(maxlength as nVarChar),LEN(cast(maxlength as nVarChar))-1),LEN(cast(maxlength as nVarChar))-2)
    WHERE maxlength IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition that your field must have quotes at the beginning and end:

```
... AND maxlength LIKE '"%"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field is blank, the length will be zero, so you will be asking for the rightmost -1 characters, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I did see it, but doesn't my Where statement assist with this? It should only Update IF maxlength <> blank?

Answer (score 0):

-- sql

```
WHERE not ( ISNULL(maxlength, '') = '' )
```

or oracle

```
WHERE not ( nvl(maxlength, '') = '' )
```

Comment: Error message b0rg: 'IS_NULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: The field literally looks like "9" or blank